# sequelize (SQL) wait untill array has been updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a list of objects that i need to update

```
router.route('/api2/user/bulk')
.put(function (req, res) {
    if(req.body.users && req.body.fieldKey)
    {
        req.body.users.forEach(function (x) {
            var updateVariable = {};
            updateVariable[req.body.fieldKey] = _.get(x, req.body.fieldKey);
            model.user.update(updateVariable, {where: {id: x.id}});
        })
    }
});
```

Now the problem with this is that node continues to execute before the loop is done. Meaning that i cannot know for certain that all has been updated if i add an `res.status(200).send('ok')` at the end.

My question is how can i make sure that the update has gone through before i send a response back to my client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `async` functionality.

```
      // Include the async package
     // Make sure you add "async" to your package.json
     async = require("async");

    // 1st para in async.each() is the array of items
      async.each(items,
    // 2nd param is the function that each item is passed to
     function(item, callback){
    // Call an asynchronous function, often a save() to DB
     item.someAsyncCall(function (){
    // Async call is done, alert via callback
      callback();
    });
    },
    // 3rd param is the function to call when everything's done
    function(err){
  // All tasks are done now
 doSomethingOnceAllAreDone();
 }
);
```

for better understanding you may google for tutorials for async js